# YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper can't use YTPlayerView class

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I am trying to implement the youtube-ios-player-helper, found here: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

What I did:
Edited my podfile, pod update, everything fine without any errors, Alamofire - which was also added via cocoapods still working

I can see the Pod in my workspace, and I can even select YTPlayerView as Class for my UIView in Storyboard

But when it comes to adding the IBOutlet it doesn't recognize the YTPlayerView Class anymore?!

[image: storyboard]
[image: collectionview cell]

Shouldn't it be impossible to even select it in storyboard if the Pod wasnt properly added?

I also tried the "manual" method, that gave a slightly better result as it would let me define the Player, but wouldn't let me import the YTPlayerView via Bridging-Header

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The YTPlayerView is in the separate Pods module which you need to import.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.3'

target 'MyApp' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'
end
```

Your Swift file:

```
import UIKit
import youtube_ios_player_helper // You're missing this line

class MyView: UIView { // Some class

    @IBOutlet var playerView: YTPlayerView!

    // ...

}
```

If `import youtube_ios_player_helper` doesn't work for you, you can add `#import "YTPlayerView.h"` to your bridging header as stated in [Fayza Nawaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289432/2415822).

Comment: You, the saviour!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the issue and fixed it by adding
    "#import YTPlayerView.h"
in bridging header file in my project. To learn about bridging header, check this link: [adding bridging header in swift ios](https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/). I hope it'll help you.